# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable - How do I identify what is causing this error?

Tags: python, function, debugging, call, typeerror

It would absolutely phenomenal if I could receive some input as to why am I receiving this type error. I have been debugging for hours, and I can't find anywhere what is causing this specific error within this function... :(

```
def a_plus_abs_b(a, b):
    if b < 0:
        f = sub(a, b)
    else:
        f = add(a, b)
    return f(a, b)
```

Comment: In your last line, what do you think is in your variable `f`?

Comment: Just return f not return f(a,b)

Comment: Did you take a close look at the traceback you get when the error is thrown? Note that including the full traceback is always a good idea; you can tell a lot from the traceback, like *what exact line* the exception was raised from.

Comment: How do I traceback my code? Is there a specific software to use? I am an absolute novice, and I really appreciate the wonderful things I am being told :)

Comment: The traceback is normally printed automatically by Python.

Comment: @user6764392: the traceback is the whole text that starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):` and ends with the exception message. You only gave us the last line, the exception message.

Comment: @user6764392: also, for this to be a proper [mcve], you should include at least stub versions of `add()` and `sub()`, some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f` is an `int` or `float`, not a function. You can't call it.

As you tried to call it `f(a, b)`, you had the error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

You should simply return `f` to avoid this.

Comment: What if `sub` or `add` are bound to numbers instead? The OP didn't include a traceback, so we can't state with certainty that it is the `f(a, b)` expression is the cause. It is a *probable* cause, of course.

Comment: OP added a portion of traceback with the title.

Comment: I feel like an idiot... but thank you!

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: no, that's not a traceback. That's only the exception message. The traceback includes the filenames, line numbers and line of code for the whole stack.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your point, completely agreed.